# What exactly is ~/org/?

Tags: org-mode

Sorry for the greenness of this question but I am starting with Org mode to replace Markdown and I don't really understand `org/`: what to do with `/` what the `org` directory is?

I looked through some basic tutorials and the Org website but I couldn't find anything concrete. I have a git repo that I store notes in (`.md` files) and I have started adding `.org` files to this repo. Is this alright or do all files have to be in the `org` directory?

Comment: The question is unclear. You speak of `~/org`, `org/`, and `org` directories. It's unclear what you're asking about any of them. And the question you pose at the end is also unclear - and is another question. One question per question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any path starting with a tilde and a slash automatically refers to your home directory. On my computer, `~/org` expands to `/home/db48x/org`; on your computer it will expand to something appropriate for your computer and username.

`org-mode` doesn’t care where the files are though; you can put them wherever you want. `~/org` is just a convenient location for a tutorial to tell you to put them, because it is short and memorable, and the tilde means that it will automatically go into your home directory; the tutorial doesn’t have to know your username or tell you to type in your username.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried certain functionality would be lost if I had files elsewhere.

Comment: @Doomer1999: if the answer has answered the question to your satisfaction, please [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). That helps future visitors who might have a similar question that there is a satisfactory answer. Clicking on the `?` icon in the upper right gets you to the Help Center which contains useful information about how the site is supposed to work.